# How to get GCM error message 'NotRegistered' using PushSharp

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to figure out how to get a Google GCM response (ie NotRegistered error) so that I may remove the GCM info from the users account.

From [GCM Archetecture Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) (in regards to unregistering a device from GCM), they state "It is only unregistered when the GCM server tries to send a message to the device and the device answers that the application is uninstalled or it does not have a broadcast receiver configured to receive com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intents. At that point, you server should mark the device as unregistered (the server will receive a NotRegistered error)."

Within PushSharp for Mono for Android; how do you get the Google Response when trying to send a message to the user and instead you receive a "NotRegistered error" from Google? To send a message, I have this code:

```
    var push = new PushService();

    // setup channel settings: sender id, access key, registration package name
    var settings = new GcmPushChannelSettings(<>, <>, <PACKAGE>);
    push.StartGoogleCloudMessagingPushService(settings);
    var android = NotificationFactory.AndroidGcm();
    android = android.ForDeviceRegistrationId(GCM_Id); 
        push.QueueNotification(android.WithJson("{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"URL\":\"" + URL + "\"}"));
```

How do I get the response from Google to know if 1. the message went through 2. the app was uninstalled or 3. getting the NotRegistered error so that I may remove the GCM Id from the users account?

Looking forward to any help I can get for this. The code above uses PushSharp for Mono for Android (MonoDroid) and it works flawlessly in sending a message to the user. [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/) is amazing and I strongly recommend it for sending messages to your user via GCM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the events attached to the `Events` property on the `PushService`.

You will then be able to receive the responses in your event handlers.

```
        //Create our service    
        PushService push = new PushService();

        //Wire up the events
        push.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += new Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionExpired(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired);
        push.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged += new Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged);
        push.Events.OnChannelException += new Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelExceptionDelegate(Events_OnChannelException);
        push.Events.OnNotificationSendFailure += new Common.ChannelEvents.NotificationSendFailureDelegate(Events_OnNotificationSendFailure);
        push.Events.OnNotificationSent += new Common.ChannelEvents.NotificationSentDelegate(Events_OnNotificationSent);
        push.Events.OnChannelCreated += new Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelCreatedDelegate(Events_OnChannelCreated);
        push.Events.OnChannelDestroyed += new Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelDestroyedDelegate(Events_OnChannelDestroyed);
```

In your event handler you can then examine the Exception and determine if you should remove the device id from the users account.

```
        static void Events_OnNotificationSendFailure(Common.Notification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
        {
            // Remove device id 
            Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + notification.Platform.ToString() + " -> " + notificationFailureException.Message + " -> " + notification.ToString());
        }
```